# What does error code E26 from TestCafe mean?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, error-code

We are running TestCafe with numerous tests on a node.js web application with Chrome. From time to time we see error messages like this:

```
Error: { code: 'E26',
  isTestCafeError: true,
  callsite:
   CallsiteRecord {
     filename:
      'step_actions.js',
     lineNum: 101,
     callsiteFrameIdx: 6,
     stackFrames:
      [ [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite],
        [CallSite] ],
     isV8Frames: true } }
```

What does this error mean? I cannot find anything about it.

We're still trying to understand, what the reason for the error is. All I know is that it is only occurring when handling a popup window.

Comment: It means that an "action element is invisible": https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/395f922f057f05adf5e541232b938c006716d554/src/errors/types.js#L30. 
Could you please update your question with a simple project (or a public URL) to reproduce the issue? Also I suggest you try the `timeout` Selector option: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/selector-options.html#optionstimeout.